# two laravel projects with exact same mail configuration: one of them goes in timout when I try to send email

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, sendgrid

I have 2 laravel projects almost identical (same `composer.json` except for a "feed package" that is present just in one of the two), with the exact same mail configuration and in the same physical server.

I do not know why one of them is not able to send email, cause I get this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [Connection timed out #110]
```

I am confused even only to fino out what search I have to do to solve it.

**UPDATE**

I was a little bit idiotic :)
My problem was I did not recreate the config mail file on the server, so I updated it physically but laravel still had the prev one config infos.

Comment: Did you check the .env file?

Comment: Yes, both of them do not have .env file, they are in production.

Comment: Port or firewall issue may be there

Comment: But they should have env files  Even if they're in production (With APP_ENV = 'production' probably). 

If you check the mail config, probably you are using a variable coming from the .env file.

Comment: How can I check it? They are in the same server (physical) and with the exact same mail.php config file.

Comment: Can you run these 2 commands to clear cache and configs.`php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: @AjayMakwana you right, that was my problem. Thank you

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro Can I Post this as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a caching feature.

So When you add/update any configuration, you need to clear those config caching.

Try with `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` to clear caching.

As this worked, I posted as an answer.